# Origin Not Coming Along With Object

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode, origin

need help on understanding why the origin is not intact with my object.

Whenever I create an object (ex. plane) and move it along the viewport, the origin is intact.
The step I do are:

- Object Mode
- Add object (ex. plane)
- Click on one object
- Hit G (to grab and move along the global axis)

[image]

But, when I try below steps, the origin is being separated from the object:

- Object mode
- Add object
- Click on object
- Hit G (to grab and move along the global axis)
- Edit mode
- Select top vertices of the object
- Extend the object (then click anywhere to set the changes)
- Select all the object
- Hit G then move the object along the axis.

From the last step, I noticed that the origin is now left out. Why does the *Object Mode* and *Edit Mode* have different approach to *Grab* function? What to do to to set the origin intact on the object while I am in edit mode?

[image]

Comment: If you are in Edit mode, you can't move the origin, you only can do it in Object mode

Comment: Hi @moonboots , if I go to OBJECT MODE, is there a way that I can put the origin to the center of the object? I tried to do it by setting the ORIGIN ON but I'm not confident that I would be able to do it manually.

Comment: right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry?

Comment: Hi @moonboots thank you for this. Now the origin is with the object again.

Comment: Although you accepted the answer on how to reset the origin, it actually ignores the origin of your question (sorry for the pun), actually stating not to know why this happens. This is - as others mentioned before - completely intentional behaviour and even more so, **it has to be like that**. In _Edit Mode_ you cannot only move all vertices together, but also a partial selection of them or single vertices. How is the origin in your understanding supposed to react to that? Move each time you move some vertices? Or relative to the percentage of moved vertices, either stay or move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Object Mode* moving an object means moving its origin (and keeping the vertices at same position relative to the object's origin).

In *Edit Mode* moving a selection means moving the vertices of the selection, in relation to the object's origin. Therefore by definition, moving something in *Edit Mode* **is not** moving the origin.

Origin always denotes $(0, 0, 0)$ coordinate. An object has a transformation matrix, which transforms the coordinate space. One effect of that is the coordinate $(0, 0, 0)$ moving away from the original origin - and that's what the orange dot [image] represents - where does the coordinate $(0, 0, 0)$ end up, after applying object's transformation matrix, as well as parent's transformation matrix, and parent's parent's transformation matrix and so on. **In Edit Mode you modify a mesh or other data object like text or curve, you don't modify the object, therefore the orange dot doesn't move.**

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure WHY this is happening - but a **quick and easy fix** is simply to **reset the origin after transformation** Even easier add a quick shortcut by right clicking on menu description - and from then on just hit Q each time it does it
[image: In the Menu]

[image: You could even add a shortcut]

[image]

Comment: It's because that's how it's supposed to work! See the second answer below from @MarcusvonBroady.